# JPA Failing to produce a proper SQL query when a parameter has a composite primary key

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Today I came across a weird bug while trying to test a JPA update query and I'm wondering if this a SpringBoot bug.

I have the following entities

An Entry entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED, force = true)
public class Entry {

@Id
private String id;
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "username")
@NotNull
private final User username;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@NotNull
private Type type;
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Category.class)
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "name"),@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "type"),@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "username")})
@NotNull
private Category category;
@Size(max = 45)
@NotBlank
private String description;
@NotNull
private Double amount;
@NotNull
private final Date createdAt;
private Timestamp lastUpdate;
@NotNull
private Boolean isDeleted;

public enum Type{
    Income,Expense
}
}
```

A Category entity with a composite key

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED, force = true)
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
@ToString(of = {"id"})
public class Category {

@EmbeddedId
private CategoryId id;
private final Timestamp createdAt = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "username")
private final User user;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "category")
private List<Entry> entries;

public Category(String name, Type type, User user){
    this.id = new CategoryId(name,type,user.getUsername());
    this.user = user;
}

}
```

A CategoryID that is the embeddable composite key of the Category entity

```
@Data
@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"name","type","username"})
public class CategoryId implements Serializable {

private String name;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Type type;
private String username;

}
```

The following repository

```
@Repository
public interface EntryRepository extends JpaRepository<Entry, String> {

Optional<Entry> findEntryById(String id);

@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
@Query(value = "UPDATE Entry e SET e.username = :username, e.type = :type, e.category = :category, e.description = :description, e.amount = :amount, e.createdAt = :date, e.lastUpdate = :lastUpdate, e.isDeleted = :isDeleted WHERE e.id = :id")
void update(@Param("id") String id,
            @Param("username") User username,
            @Param("type") Entry.Type type,
            @Param("category") Category category,
            @Param("description") String description,
            @Param("amount") Double amount,
            @Param("date") Date date,
            @Param("lastUpdate") Timestamp lastUpdate,
            @Param("isDeleted") Boolean isDeleted);
 }
```

And finally the following Unit Test

```
@Test
void update() {

    //given
    User testUser = userRepository.save(new User("testUser@test.com","000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"));
    Category testCategory = categoryRepository.save(new Category("Test Category", Entry.Type.Income,testUser));
    Entry testEntry = new Entry("testEntry",testUser, Entry.Type.Income,
            testCategory, "test",
            0.0, new Date(343), from(now()), false);
    System.out.println(testCategory);
    entryRepositoryUnderTest.save(testEntry);

    //when
    entryRepositoryUnderTest.update("testEntry",testUser,Expense,testCategory,"testUpdated",1.0,new Date(346), from(now()),true);
    Optional<Entry> actual = entryRepositoryUnderTest.findEntryById("testEntry");
    System.out.println(actual.get().getCategory());
    //then
    assertThat(actual.get().getUsername()).isEqualTo(testUser);
    assertThat(actual.get().getType()).isEqualTo(Expense);
    assertThat(actual.get().getCategory()).isEqualTo(testCategory);
    assertThat(actual.get().getDescription()).isEqualTo("testUpdated");
    assertThat(actual.get().getAmount()).isEqualTo(1.0);
    assertThat(actual.get().getIsDeleted()).isEqualTo(true);
}
```

When I run the test it fails and I get the following error message:

could not execute update query; SQL [update entry set username_username=?, type=?,category_name=?=category_type=?, description=?, amount=?, created_at=?, last_update=?, is_deleted=? where id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute update query

As you can see here when SpringBoot is trying to produce a SQL query statement from my @Query parameter it can not properly extract the Category field from the parameters and inject it's composite embeddable key into the SQL statement. It has no problem extracting the User parameter because the User is an entity with an id that is not composite.

Is this a SpringBoot bug or am I missing something?

EDIT:
This is the structure of the database

[image]

Comment: Can you also share your `Entry` table structure?

Comment: @Rohit done, any ideas?

Comment: JPA needs to know the name of the column that references the foreign key. Add the name attribute to the Joincolumn
`@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="category_name", referencedColumnName = "name"),@JoinColumn(name="category_type",referencedColumnName = "type"),@JoinColumn(name="category_username", referencedColumnName = "username")})`

Comment: @Rohit still doesnt work.